# Keep a base version of a file on remote repository but an updated version locally

Tags: git

I have 2 files, `database.db` and `schema.sql`. schema.sql is generated in the database using the command:

```
sqlite3 database.db < schema.sql
```

The database.db is then updated dynamically locally. The question I want solved is that the version of database.db I want on my remote repository is the one that just contains the tables and table rows as declared in schema.sql. The goal here is that I don't want merge conflicts in database.db as we are multiple people working on this repository and we are likely to want to have different databases.

So far I have only tried adding database.db to the repository's .gitignore which doesn't work.

Comment: Choose a different procedure that does not require you to keep a locally modified tracked file. It only leads to major headaches as the many SO posts about [how to ignore changes in tracked file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+to+ignore+changes+in+tracked+file) demonstrate.

Comment: Track `schema.sql` instead of `database.db`. Maintain your own `database.db` out of the repository.

Comment: Don't track the db file or check the `skip-worktree` feature https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/717372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question I want solved is that the version of database.db I want on my remote repository is the one that just contains the tables and table rows as declared in `schema.sql`

Then work with two different database.db files:

- one (`database.gen.sql`) which is tracked and pushed, and just contains the tables and table rows as declared in `schema.sql`: `sqlite3 database.gen.sql < schema.sql`
- one (`database.sql`) which is is copied from `database.gen.sql` and then modified privately by developers, meaning this one can be added to the `.gitignore`.